# Why Ctrl+F5 is not working with my vtk code in Visual C++ debugging

Tags: vtk

I am a vtk beginner.There's a strange problem confused for long.I have written a VTK console application by vs2017.If I run it in vs2017 with ctrl+f5,it will show the following picture as error.But, if I directly run it in application work directory,it will operate normally.Why this problem occured?Anyone could help me, thanks a lot.
[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T70nw.png)

my c++ code is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPNGReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPNGReader>::New();
    reader->SetFileName("fruit.png");

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2> imageViewer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2>::New();
    imageViewer->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    imageViewer->SetupInteractor(renderWindowInteractor);
    imageViewer->Render();
    imageViewer->GetRenderer()->ResetCamera();
    imageViewer->Render();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkJPEGWriter> writer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkJPEGWriter>::New();
    writer->SetFileName("fruit.jpg");
    writer->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
    writer->Write();

    renderWindowInteractor->Start();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please don't post images of text, copy-paste the text instead. And mark out in the code (with comments) where the errors are.

Comment: You need to set the working directory in Visual Studio for the debugger to where your image file is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Visual Studio isn't looking in your application work directory for fruit.png, instead it's looking in your project directory.

Go to Project/Properties/Debugging/Working Directory and change the value there to whatever your application work directory is.